# Team Foundation Server Create New Project Fails - Code TFS30159

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015, team-project

When attempting to create a new team project in TFS I'm getting the following error:

Error 
TF30170: The plugin Microsoft.ProjectCreationWizard.Classification failed during task UploadStructure from group Classification.

Explanation 
Plugin error text: “TF30159: Error occurred while updating project description for "vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/9faf261d-b680-439f-ad23-e4afefc22b0e"”

User Action 
Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.

Here is a copy of the log where the exception is thrown:

---begin Exception entry---

Time: 2016-03-10T11:24:34
Module: Engine
Event Description: TF30162: Task "UploadStructure" from Group "Classification" failed
Exception Type: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.PcwException
Exception Message: TF30159: Error occurred while updating project description for "vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/29bfb07e-5578-4bdc-96d1-ec1b1d33a186"
Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.CssStructureUploader.SetProjectDescription(ProjectCreationContext context, String projectUri)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.CssStructureUploader.Execute(ProjectCreationContext context, XmlNode taskXml)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.ProjectCreationEngine.TaskExecutor.PerformTask(IProjectComponentCreator componentCreator, ProjectCreationContext context, XmlNode taskXml)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.ProjectCreationEngine.RunTask(Object taskObj)
--   Inner Exception   --
Exception Message: Method Not Allowed (type VssServiceResponseException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.d__49.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.d__47`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__53`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.d__52`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.CssStructureUploader.SetProjectDescription(ProjectCreationContext context, String projectUri)

--- end Exception entry ---

I think it might be something to do with the projectUri but I'm not sure.

if I try to access the project via the url: 
vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/29bfb07e-5578-4bdc-96d1-ec1b1d33a186

I get the following TFS error:

[image]

However I'm not sure if this error is simply because the create is failing or whether it is causing it.

Any ideas about what is causing this and how to fix it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this TFS 2015 new installed? Have you created a team project before? Try to create a team project on another machine to see whether you can create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try on another client machine to create a team project to clarify whether the issue is from server side or client side.
2. Check TFS installation whether it meets the [requirement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/tfs/administer/requirements).
3. Clean user cache: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache`.
4. Repair VS/Team Explorer.

Comment: I don't have access to another local machine to test, but I've installed VS2015 on the server and managed to successfully create a team project that way.  However the disk space is limited so it isn't really an option.  I've re-installed Visual Studio locally, and cleared the cache etc... still getting the same issue.  I'm behind quite a strict proxy and I've had to add it to my devenv.config - do you think the plugin might be  having issues with that?  I'm completely out of ideas with this one

Comment: It could be. But in the log file you provided, we don't see proxy error. Can you connect to the team project that you have created on your local machine? Would you get any error message?

Comment: Thanks for answer - point one confirmed it was a problem on the client not the server, repair didn't work, but a clean re-install after deleting all app data seemed to do the trick...